# how to get probability of each class using functional api of keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I always get one hot encoded output, e.i [0, 1, 0], whereas I'd like to get output such as [0.1, 0.95, 0.1]

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
image = load_img(os.path.join('happy_dog.jpg')) 
image = image.convert('L')
image = image.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

imgarray = img_to_array(image)
np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)

predict = model.predict([[imgarray]], verbose=0)
print(predict[0])
```

array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)

Comment: [0, 1, 0] are also probabilities, and importantly, make sure that you apply any normalization used to train the model to your new input images.

Comment: Such sharp output probabilities is a possible indicator of the fact that you have not done the same input data normalization in test phase as it was done in training phase.

Comment: ok i will add the normalization and share the results